# Why do Git-related questions have hundreds of upvotes?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that a lot of Git-related questions and answers have hundreds of upvotes, more than for any other tag.

Does anyone have ideas why that is?

Comment: Nobody reading the manual and instead doing a web search, ending on SO/SU?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=edit+commit+message+git Add to that, that the particular question that points to has been around for 5 years. The same goes for various other Git questions.

Comment: Because Git has a steep learning curve, and its hard to go through the manuals to do trivial tasks, So a bit of google and an SO question would be there to help you. I remember upvoting some Git questions as well.

Comment: Because nobody gits it.

Comment: @Emrakul That amused me more than it really should have

Comment: @Bart You tend to oscillate quite a lot, I find.

Comment: I am one of those people whose answers get a huge number of upvotes. I feel guilty for getting so many internet points for simple answers that I don't maintain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say it's because of the difference between a reference manual and a tutorial: Git has a very thorough documentation that describes all the ways to operate it, but it doesn't have a good inverse mapping – given a problem, what are the right operations to use in which order to solve the problem? Couple that with the fact that Git has a lot of overlap in vocabulary but difference in meaning to other revision control systems, and you have the situation where people have a good idea of what they want to accomplish but are unfamiliar with the idioms of the system.

So questions like "How do I do X in Git?" are very common, and occur to almost everyone who is serious about using Git but not intimately familiar with it. You know that it surely can be done, but which specific sequence of branching, tagging, pulling, fetching, resetting, reverting and rebasing accomplishes this is tricky to figure out. And there's Stack Overflow to the rescue.

For what it's worth, half the time I have an operational question about Git, I find a good tutorial on GitHub, but Stack Overflow is definitely one of the main resources.

Answer (score 11):

The Stack Exchange is high on the google index when you search many git related queries.

Therefore when people find what they are looking for they upvote if they have an account :-)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too. It was just so noticeable how often I would search something Git related and end up in a question that has like 300 or 700 upvotes.

Comment: @satuon Git is not limited to a programming language too, so you have a broader audience too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Developers of nearly every platform and language are using Git these days.

   1. Therefore, it would stand to reason that Git questions are frequently **viewed**.
2. People are generally asking the same questions about Git usage (i.e. How do I begin?, How do I commit?, How do I pull?, How do I fork?, etc).

   1. With less variance in the questions being asked, it would stand to reason that the existing ones address common problems and are therefore heavily **upvoted**.

Comment: I disagree. Lots of people use Java and C++, but most of the reference questions for those tags don't have as many votes.

Comment: @Emrakul: That's a fair point. Please see my revision.